# Disable CPU halt state to prevent BSOD/KSOD

Tags: cpu, bsod, acpi, black-screen-of-death

I have recently had problems with my Windows7 desktop bluescreening several times per day (with many different STOP codes) and occasionally blackscreening. Because it is still under manufacturer's warranty, I have been in contact with tech support. The most recent communication I've received instructed me to **disable the halt state** in the boot menu to avoid any further problems. Is this an acceptable solution? Or is this a way to cover faulty hardware? If either the memory or CPU (or any other hardware) *is* indeed faulty, will it (or could it) fail even if the halt state is diabled?

Comment: upload the .dmp files so that we can look at them with the debugger.

Comment: Lost some of them. but I have three [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/430178/041213-13556-01.dmp) [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/430179/041513-17971-01.dmp) and [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/430180/041513-22869-01.dmp).

Comment: I don't insert my email to get a link. Upload it them as 1 zip to skydrive or dropbox.

Comment: @magicandre1981 [Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!7xA2hYSY!ejz_vhb5jXyfMspM6468U14egbFFXGle5fnc56AItIQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 250 has L1 Cache issue which causes the BSOD. Send the PC to them to replace the CPU:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa8004b49038, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000b6004000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000075000135, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_AuthenticAMD

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
hal!HalBugCheckSystem
nt!WheaReportHwError
hal!HalpMcaReportError
hal!HalpMceHandler
hal!HalHandleMcheck
nt!KxMcheckAbort
nt!KiMcheckAbort
0x0



STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: AuthenticAMD


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE

===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa8004b49038
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01ce39d2ae0bcf43
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 4/15/2013 12:19:08 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004b490b8
Section       @ fffffa8004b49190
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Read
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000100f63
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004b49100
Section       @ fffffa8004b49250
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : 63 0f 10 00 00 08 02 00 - 09 20 80 00 ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa8004b49250

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004b49148
Section       @ fffffa8004b492d0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : DCACHEL1_DRD_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 0)
  Status      : 0xb600400075000135
  Address     : 0x0000000010f47880
  Misc.       : 0x0000000000000000
```